# sqlcmd in bash file - store to variable

Tags: bash, sqlcmd

Running in a docker container, I am trying to determine if a table exits in the mssql database:

```
RESULT='/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'MyTable'"'
    if [ "$RESULT" == "MyTable" ]; then
        echo YES
    fi
    echo "$RESULT"
```

`echo "$RESULT"` always just outputs the entire command as a string, its not getting executed.  So its just assigning it as a sting...

How can I execute it and assign the result?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RESULT=$(...)`? and not `RESULT='...'`?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash does not execute commands defined in single quotes. Single quotes are used for string definitions.

What you try to do is called **command substitution**. And it can be done in two different ways:

```
RESULT=`command` 
RESULT=$(command)
```

So your example should look like this:

```
RESULT=`/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyTable'`
if [ "$RESULT" == "MyTable" ]; then
    echo YES
fi
echo "$RESULT"
```

You can find more information regarding command substitution here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html