# Assign a SQL Server query value to a variable in shell script

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, sh

I have tried to assign as SQL query value to a variable so that based on its value I will trigger my ETL job in the shell script.

I tried something like below.

```
echo off
status='sqlcmd -S {host} -d {db} -U {user} -P {password} -Q "SELECT CASE WHEN fc.config_val< fc.config_val_dev_mysql AND fc.config_val < fc.config_val_prod_mysql THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS mssql_status FROM flex_configs fc;"';
echo $status
```

But this is not working.

If the status = 1 then I will trigger the ETL job in the same shell script if not I do nothing. Please suggest me the answer as I am unable to get this script.

Comment: Does no one have this answer.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlcmd in bash file - store to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105736/sqlcmd-in-bash-file-store-to-variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
status=$(sqlcmd -S {host} -d {db} -U {user} -P {password} -Q "SELECT CASE WHEN fc.config_val< fc.config_val_dev_mysql AND fc.config_val < fc.config_val_prod_mysql THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS mssql_status FROM flex_configs fc;")
echo $status
```

You need to put code inside  `$()` like `$(my code)` or `` `my code` ``